# Generate PDF having image in header using Phantomjs 1.9.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs

I am using printheaderfooter.js to generate PDF from html using Phantomjs 1.9.7.
I want to display image in header.

```
    var PhantomJSPrinting = {
        header: {
          height: "1cm",
          contents: function(pageNum, numPages) { 

               return '<img src="https://www.google.com.bo/images/srpr/logo4w.png"  height="0.95cm"/>'; 

          }
      }  };
```

But, PDF generated with blank header. No image displayed in header.

Any solution to display images in header?

Answer (score 0):

The height property doesn't seem to work.

Use CSS style property instead.

`return '<img src="https://www.google.com.bo/images/srpr/logo4w.png" style="height:0.95cm" />';`